# Java library for CSS cleanup

Tags: java, html, css

For a rich text editor that has to handle pasted HTML code from MS Office applications, I'm looking for a Java library that cleans up the content of all "style" attributes in HTML elements, so that only some CSS attributes are left:

- background-color
- border
- color
- font-family
- font-weight
- font-style
- list-style-type
- text-align
- text-decoration
- vertical-align

For creating a well-formed HTML document, I can use JTidy. For HTML element transformations (removing unwanted elements), I can use http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Is there anything comparable for CSS attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a some CSS parser (like http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) and [SAC](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/).